# android installer is showing as update despite of absence of previous versions

Tags: android

I created an app with LiveCode and installed it on my tablet (Jelly Bean 4.1.2) few times. I'm not able to install the latest version of the app nor the older versions that were installed without any problems before. When I tap to install the app the message asks if I want to install an update to existing application despite that the previous versions are uninstalled. When I tap on Install the message comes:  "App not installed". The app is about 7 MB and I have plenty of space on the tablet.  What is the reason for this problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you provide a `logcat`?

Comment: Are you installing those apps from the same source? Check their signatures if possible.

Comment: try to uninstall the apk using this adb command:
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.DELETE -d package:<your app package>
Once it is correctly uninstalled you could install it again

Comment: @ wiz3kid: I'm not familiar with logcat - where/how do i find it?

Comment: @ shkschneider: Yes, same source and the setting in LiveCode is "Sign for development only"

Comment: @ gyss: that app is not showing up as installed so there is nothing to uninstall; in any case I could try your solution, but how do I use that command? where do I put it? I'm a complete beginner in this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the app Identifier in the standalone settings fixed the problem.